# Dynamically add content in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an Facebook desktop application to fetch past 20 facebook statuses. Since I am a newbie, I am not sure how to fit this in the UI. I am able to do this in Console by just writing a for loop. How about windows forms? How do I get dynamic content and display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way of doing that would be to create  Labels at runtime and then add them to the form in a loop. Something on the following lines

```
    foreach (var status in facebookStatus)
    {
        Label lblStatus = new Label();
        lblStatus.Text = status;
        this.Controls.Add(lblStatus);
    }
```

This is just for starting up your work, later you may need your own control to display the status, and then you may add that control to the form.

Comment: Hi, thnx for your help. I want them to be implemented in a panel with scroll functionality. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a lot to learn about Winforms, and that this question wouldn't be an issue if you were already familiar with it :-)

That said, you can still use a loop, but instead of outputting to the console, you can add some representation of the data to your view. For your application, some custom UserControl derivative seems appropriate, and you can add them to a FlowLayoutPanel to easily handle positioning.

Comment: yeah, I am just learning c# for my hobby projects:) thnx for helping

Answer (score 0):

To start, create a DataGridView: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx
Set its data source to the set of data you get from facebook and it will render all the data in the columns you set up.

For a more advanced technique, create a control that has a DataSource property similar to the DataGridView, but renders each item of data as some custom control.  Good luck, use the MSDN documentation heavily - Winforms are very well documented.